# Regular expression to validate Customer name of format ABC PVT (ltd)

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation

I have to validate a customer name. The following are the valid criteria  for customer name

1. A customer name can start with letters digits
2. It can have    alphabets digits  (.) hyphen(-) and ampersand
   or ( in between
3. It should end with alphabets number or can have spaces. or
       closing ')'
4. Valid names example 'ABC pvt ltd', 'A.B.C' 'L&T'
5. Ideally  It should match  only if parenthesis open onced should be closed.

This is my regex

```
<code>
      (^[a-zA-Z\s][a-zA-Z0-9-&\'\\.\\(\s]+[a-zA-Z0-9\s\\.\\)]
</code>
```

Can this be made more elegant?

Issue with current regex

1. It matches E(test
2. The regex is very long

Comment: `-` is not `_`. The former is a "hyphen", the latter is an "underscore"

Comment: good luck matching those `)` when you can have any number of `(` before it.  I think you will find Regx ill suited for this.  You probably have to tokenise it and iterate though it.

Comment: Is that possible

Comment: If I had time I would show you how, but i dont, so I can show you how I use Regx to process JSON,  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/JasonDecoder.php  by tokenizing it.

Comment: you can try it here live http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2917e4bb8ef847df97edbf0bb8f415a10d13c9f

Comment: if I ignore the condition that parenthesis has to be matched.Can the above regex be made simpler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160430/discussion-between-tes-and-artisticphoenix).

Answer (score 3):

You violated your own first rule even, you may go with:

```
(?i)^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9 (.&-](?(?<=\()(?=[^()]++\)$)))*[a-z0-9) ]$
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/gOC4z3/3)**

Comment: It succesfully fails to validate `f(x)(`, but erroneously accepts `f((x)`. To validate matching, nested parentheses you can use the [`(?R)`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) operator. But are you sure that a company name, according to your local company register, can't contain an open parenthesis without a matching close parenthesis? Be careful your validator is not so strict that it rejects real company names.

Comment: I agree with your first statement, fixed it. But not sure whether or not nested parentheses should be allowed since it's a name field. @SimonShine